# What is the irregular signal at the bottom of this "spectrogram"?

Tags: rf, radio, lora, spectrum, spread-spectrum

I am reading research papers about LoRa, and I have come across the below figure in [this one](https://www.mdpi.com/1424-8220/18/9/2853).
The horizontal axis is clearly labeled frequency, but the vertical one isn't. I recognize the chirps in the middle, so I understand that the vertical axis is indeed time for that graph, but I still have no idea what the other, darker blue graph represents. Could you shed some light on this please?

[image: LoRa spectrogram]

Comment: Looks like noise to me.

Comment: I was thinking the same, but with what parameters?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean here.  Looks like the Noise Floor to me.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noise_floor

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense, then the value is about -90 dBm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's two diagrams in one:

1. The background one, the turquoise zig-zag, is called a waterfall; the vertical axis is time, the horizontal is frequency, and power is coded into color.
2. the line at the bottom is something else; maybe just a time trace; it's at the very least not a representation of the spectrum at the same bandwidth, because otherwise, the center would have to have higher amplitude (where the zigzagging happens)

Generally, if a figure is unclear, that's *a fault in the publication you're reading*, and since this curve isn't described any further, I'd recommend ignoring it.

Comment: Exactly what I was thinking, thank you for the clear answer. Isn't waterfall a different, 3D representation of the spectrogram?

Comment: @Boba0514 yes, a waterfall is a spectrogram with time. Not 3D like a 3D shape, but 3D like a 2D graph with colour.

Comment: yep, and in this case, the third dimension is the color.

Comment: I see, wikipedia's definition confused me then. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

These are two different traces.

- The blue one at the bottom is the raw signal with its received power (in dBm, left scale) vs. time. -90 dBm is 1 pW of received power.
- The colored one is the spectrogram with time on the vertical axis and frequency on the horizontal axis.

Comment: never saw amplitude over time being given in dB!

Comment: @MarcusMüller  Sorry, that should read signal power in dBm in this case - but sure, dB can be used to measure the amplitude of a signal as well.

Comment: of course it can, but honestly, I've never seen that be done as plot over time. The utility of such a plot would be pretty specific, so I'll venture a guess that you're not completely right about that.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking about something like this, but if that's so, it is a terrible way to plot it here, since time is already used on the other axis, and the horizontal axis doesn't have a secondary labeling...

Comment: @Boba0514 : The horizontal axis has two labels. "500 kHz span" and "100 ms/div". Although it's not clear what a division is as the marks are missing. As Marcus wrote - it's not a good graphic.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. Thank you for the help.